# Custom List of contacts - First Letter Icon colors reference

Tags: android

I have a custom list of contacts on my app (from custom SqlLite table). I want to follow the Android's looks like, and show the contact icon like Android do when the standard Contact has not a picture (shows the first letter in a box with a background color).

I can see that Android have a different background color depending of the letter, im right?

[image]

Is there any color reference table for those letters? or maybe a programmatically why to get this color?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean Gmail first character box? Take some screen shots of the different charactes, copy them on your PC, discover the colors used for each character and use them in your app.

Comment: Hi Frank!, actually not just Gmail use this "first character box", People app use it too. I was looking more deeply on that and the assigned color is random. Thanks anyway